# React native login state across entire app

Tags: authentication, react-native

My home screen exists of a StackNavigator which is inside a DrawerNavigator. Code:

```
const HomeNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Index: { screen: ScreenHome },
    Register: { screen: ScreenRegister },
});

const App = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeNavigator }
},{
    contentComponent: (navigation) => <ScreenMenu navigation={navigation}/>
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactApp', () => App);
```

After logging in through a REST Service i want to pass the loggedIn state to all my other screens. But how should i do this? Should i declare a Authentication Component which will be passed to all the screens? Or is there another best practice for a global login state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) for setting up a global state for the app.